# Mono xbuild: Copy debug symbols from NuGet packages folder into output bin folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, nuget, xbuild

When using NuGet packages which include symbols, Visual Studio is copying these debug symbol files (`*.pdb`) right into the bin output folder.

This does not happen when using NuGet and `xbuild` on Linux using Mono - the `pdb` files are not copied to the output folder.

Is there any way to let `xbuild` mimic the pdb-copying behavior of Visual Studio?

Comment: xbuild does not generate .pdb files. It creates .mdb files which are not the same as .pdb.

Comment: Yes, totally aware of that. What I'm trying to achieve is having `xbuild` mimicking Visual Studio's behaviour in copying the already present pdb files from the nuget packages folder to the output folder.

Comment: @MattWard sorry, just realized who you are. Since you're maintaining the NuGet plugin for Monodevelop,  do you think my question makes any sense? Also taking my script into account which should visualize quite well what I'm trying to do (see below). Basically I want to take advantage of the pdbs coming from NuGet on Mono the same way I can on Windows/Visual Studio -  having them copied from the packages to the bin folder  in order to take and deploy it from there. Converting them to mdb  is just an additional step I'm doing for convenience.

Comment: It would be nice if Xamarin Studio supported NuGet symbol packages and everything would work out of the box so you can step into the NuGet package source code. The copying of the .pdb files is done on Windows by MSBuild and not by NuGet. xbuild is doing the equivalent but only understands mdb files so it ignores the pdbs. So I think with your script it should instead generate the .mdb files in the packages directory then hopefully xbuild would just copy the .mdb files when it builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I was able to achieve what I wanted by writing this script, which also converts the pdb files to mdb (requires `pdb2mdb` to be in the path):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PACKAGE_PATH_SUBSTR=$1
CSPROJ=$2
OUT_DIR=$3

# 1.) search for file references in the .csproj file with the help of the partial nuget package path name
# 2.) replace .dll with .pdb
# 3.) replace all left <HintPath> and </HintPath> tags
# 4.) replace windows path separators (\) with unix ones (/)
PDB_CANDIDATES=$(grep -oP '<HintPath>(.*'${PACKAGE_PATH_SUBSTR}'.*\.dll)</HintPath>' $CSPROJ | sed -e "s/\.dll/\.pdb/g" | sed -e 's/<\(\/\)\{0,1\}HintPath>//g' | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' )

# loop through all possibly existent pdb file names
for item in ${PDB_CANDIDATES}; do
        # check if the pdb file candidate really exists
        if [ -e $item ]; then
                # pdb exists, copy it to the bin output path
                cp -v ${item} ${OUT_DIR}
                # convert pdb to mdb
                pdb2mdb ${OUT_DIR}/$(basename $(echo $item | sed -e 's/\.pdb/.dll/g') )
                # if you wanted you could delete the pdb file now.
        fi
done
```

Usage:
`copy_pdb_from_nuget.sh packages MyProject.csproj ./bin`